# Multithreading issue in updating UITableView using animation

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a View Model class which has a property(array) which acts as the datasource for an UITableView.

I am performing some background task in my VM. It appends the element in datasource and asks my View Controller to update the table view using `insertRows` method. The VC is queuing this update on the main queue.

Before the update completes, another background task appends an element in the datasource and VM asks VC to insert a row in the tableview.

When VC tries to insert cells for first call, it finds that there is mismatch b/w datasource elements and indexPaths I am trying to insert. (Internal Consistency Exception) and my app crashes.

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

-------------- Edit: Adding Code ----------

My VM has a delegate, which is used by VM to notify VC.

```
var dataFields: [FieldVM] = []
weak var delegate: Delegate?

// At some point in code:
while(some_condition) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        self?.dataFields.append(field)
        //Some logic to find indexPaths
        self?.delegate.insertFields(at: indexPaths)
    }
}
```

**Note: I can't simply keep the variable to store all the indexPaths and then call the delegate method as this method can be called from multiple places. So I need a generic solution.**

My VC has implemented the protocol, giving implementation to following method:

```
func insertFields(at indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self?.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .bottom)
        self?.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: please  include sample code for better understanding

Comment: Added code, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: can you try deboncer : https://blog.hellocode.co/post/debounce-swift/

Comment: @Bhavesh.iosDev Debouncing is not the right solution for my use case as I need to have those calls propagated to respective VC else there would be mismatch in update cycle of cells.

Comment: how did you end up solving this? @schinj

Comment: @jeh Still looking for the solution.

Comment: Either update your datasource inside the dispatch main async block before the begin updates call. Or move your dispatch main async block around where you are appending to your array/calling delegate (and remove the block from insert fields method)  Or create a copy of your array which the table view is using for data source and when your real array is updated, save a copy down and update the tableview so your datasource is not changed in the background.

Comment: The trick is the model update and tableview insert is on the same thread and they occur in the correct order by dispatching to the main queue serially

Answer (score 0):

That is expected when trying to access the same resource by multiple threads and alter or update the UI accordingly.

You need to control the insertRow in the tableView by adding beginAnimation before the insertRow, and endAnimation after the row in order to preserve the UI process, please note that that can cause some lag when updating the UI.